# Could you help me to understand block types when added to containers (NSDictionary, NSArray)?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

Normally blocks can be of 3 types: NSGlobalBlock, NSStackBlock, NSMallocBlock. Lets take the following example:

```
    void (^aBlock)(NSString *someString) = ^(NSString *someString){
        NSLog(@"Block was executed. %@", someString);
    };
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aBlock forKey:@"aBlock"];
```

Because aBlock doesn't capture surrounding scope if I do **po dictionary** I get

aBlock = <**NSGlobalBlock**:0x165dde60> and this is correct

If I then do a:

```
    NSString *string = @"Test";
    void (^aBlock)(NSString *someString) = ^(NSString *someString){
        NSLog(@"Block was executed. %@ %@", someString, string);
    };
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aBlock forKey:@"aBlock"];
```

and then **po dictionary**, I get:

aBlock = <**NSMallocBlock**:0x165dde60> **and this is what confuses me**

Shouldn't this be a **NSStackBlock** and only become a **NSMallocBlock** when I do:

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[aBlock copy] forKey:@"aBlock"];
```

I am on iOS 7.1 using ARC and as far as I know blocks should not be copied by default in ARC when passed down the stack and they should be copied only when passed up the stack (returning from a function).

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: i dont see how you could expect being able to add *stack* allocated memory to a dictionary. for the block to persist it needs to be on the heap. Anyhow, my guess is that in this case `NSMallocBlock` is determined at compile time because the compiler can see that it will be needed outside the stack frame.

Comment: Hi, your comment is valid about the stack vs heap, my confusion comes from the fact that the docs specifically say that even under ARC when we're adding a locally scoped block to a dictionary we have to copy it (to basically move it to the heap) and in the current case the block is already in the heap when according to the docs it shouldn't be. Maybe the docs are out of date but until I know something for sure I was thinking of just using a NSMapTable and set it to copy its values. To me that seems to be the safest approach.

Comment: can you edit your post to contain that information? it would have been helpful to know. (specifically a link to the documentation you reference). I take it this isnt a dictionary that you are trying to persist outside the local scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the block object in the dictionary was already NSMallocBlock on these lines, not from copied by NSDictionary +dictionaryWithObject:forKey: method.

```
void (^aBlock)(NSString *someString) = ^(NSString *someString){
    NSLog(@"Block was executed. %@ %@", someString, string);
};
```

This aBlock variable is __strong by the default under ARC compilation environment.

```
__strong void (^aBlock)(NSString *someString) = ^(NSString *someString){
...
```

So the block object was retained by the aBlock variable. Actually, according to LLVM source code, the compiler emitted **retain** code for storing the object into __strong variable on the line.

1. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp#L2091
2. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp#L2109
3. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp#L1920
4. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp#L1944

EmitARCRetainBlock:

```
llvm::Value *CodeGenFunction::EmitARCRetainBlock(llvm::Value *value, bool mandatory) {
    llvm::Value *result = emitARCValueOperation(*this, value,
        CGM.getARCEntrypoints().objc_retainBlock, "objc_retainBlock");
```

This *objc_retainBlock* is a runtime function in objc4.

http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/NSObject.mm

```
id objc_retainBlock(id x) {
    return (id)_Block_copy(x);
}
```

Thus, the block object was copied from stack to heap by this _Block_copy.

In addition to this, you can see **__NSStackBlock__** type for the block object using **__weak**.

```
__weak void (^aBlock)(NSString *someString) = ^(NSString *someString){
    NSLog(@"Block was executed. %@ %@", someString, string);
};
```

In this case, the block object was not retained by the aBlock variable, and the block object is not an ordinary Objective-C object, so the block object can exist on stack. Yes, it is **__NSStackBlock__** object. You may need to call **copy** or **Block_copy** for it ahead of storing into NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right, for some reason I looked at an out of date Transitioning to ARC Release Notes doc where it said: "Blocks "just work" when you pass blocks up the stack in ARC mode, such as in a return. You don’t have to call Block Copy any more. You still need to use [^{} copy] when passing "down" the stack into arrayWithObjects: and other methods that do a retain.". I looked up again that doc and in the current version I find online this last sentence is missing so I guess under ARC I don't have to worry about this anymore even though it wasn't always like this.